# How to enable authentication with external Identity Manager with WSO2 ID?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 Identity Manager. We have a requirement to verify user credentials and authorization by making a call to NetIQ Identity and Access Management.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the NetIQ Identity and Access Management solution; looks like it supports OAuth2 and OpenID Connect protocols. You can use federated authentication capabilities of WSO2 Identity Server to achieve what you want. The following documentation links will help you.

**Identity Federation:** https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/identity-federation

**Adding and Configuring an Identity Provider:** https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/adding-and-configuring-an-identity-provider/

**Configuring OAuth2-OpenID Connect:** https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+OAuth2-OpenID+Connect